# Access the powershell console (package manager console) of visual studio programmatically in an extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, powershell, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to develop a visual studio extension to automate parts of our entity framework migration process.  I checked to add migration programmatically but after looking at entity framework source, a lot is done in powershell scripts, so I would like to get a hook on the package manager console (nuget) and send a command there and read the result from the console if possible.

How do I access the package manager console programmatically in a visual studio extension?

For example I would like to send the following command to the package manager console.

```
add-migration migration01
```

Comment: Did you get anywhere with your extension?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  It was a "nice to have", there were a lot of new stuff to dig in for me so I chose the easy path and write the line I needed in the package manager console manually.

Answer (score 2):

The best way for running a script in package manager console is parameter passing into it.

```
EnvDTE.DTE _ObjDTE;
_ObjDTE = (DTE)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE");
var script = "function global:SaveAll {write-host \"All files saved.\"} SaveAll";
_ObjDTE.ExecuteCommand("View.PackageManagerConsole", script);
```

Comment: Thanks. I was looking to access Package Manager from code and your answer helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Nuget distribution available as Nuget which makes all Nuget functionality easily available, simply get the following http://nuget.codeplex.com/ package and use it.

It also has a PackageManager...

I guess something like that could install something:

```
 new PackageManager(
    PackageRepositoryFactory.Default.CreateRepository("source"), 
    "path").InstallPackage("packageId")
```

Comment: That's the nuget installed on visual studio.  I already have it.  What I want to know is how to access it programmatically in an extension in visual studio, using the dte or something.  I saw that there is an api to use nuget but it seems to have only functionalities for packages management, I haven't see anything to send a custom command string to the package manager console (to use entity framework powershell api).

Comment: see edit, with the Nuget lib you should be able to instantiate a PackageManager and install packages